# which windows explorer replacement should i use?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm hunting for a windows explorer replacement and want to get views on available tools. Looking for non-shareware.

Comment: Here are the Google results for "best windows explorer replacement" in the past year: http://www.google.ca/search?q=best+windows+explorer+replacement&btnG=Search&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&tbs=qdr%3Ay&sa=2

Comment: I am hoping for some insights from people who've actually used them. Sometimes a list of feature doesn't tell you if the tool is easy to use or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, personally I like Windows Explorer as-is, however, on top of that, I don't know why you want to get rid of shareware because [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) is brilliant!

Apart from that I used [Explorer XP](http://www.explorerxp.com/) in the past and liked it.

As for reviews, there isn't really one answer fits all, I like these tools but it depends how you want to use them - do you want something to make file operations easier, opening files better, picture gallery/viewer etc.

Another one to look at is [Free Commander](http://www.freecommander.com/index.htm).

Whatever you choose, I recommend you test thoroughly inside a VM to make sure it works the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_file_managers) should interest you...

But the more convenient I have used is not a replacement but a freeware explorer plugin: [QTTabBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qttabbar/) - It has all features I need and, as a plugin, doesn't break any shell feature