# Which Windows Explorer replacements have this feature: takes over folder open operations?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, software-rec

There have been at least a few threads about Explorer replacements, aka alternative file managers, here on Superuser. The go-to thread seems to be this one: 
https://superuser.com/q/90/60860

But what I would like to have is a narrower subset of these available choices with the feature that I indicated in the title: that is, I am interested only in such Explorer replacements which integrate themselves with Windows and do not need to be opened or launched. In other words, if I double click a folder, then the folder would be opened by this Explorer replacement. This is in contrast to how many alternative file managers are, which do not take over from Explorer. I did some searching, and user fluxtendu [linked](https://superuser.com/a/89731/60860) a cool [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_file_managers) containing feature comparisons between file managers, but unfortunately it doesn't mention the feature that I'm looking for.

I am already aware from personal experience of one that fulfills this criterion: Explorer++. And I was [told](https://superuser.com/a/268870/60860) by afrazier that Directory Opus and explorer2 also do this. What other options exist?

And of course, I would also appreciate recommendations. I guess I wasn't totally happy with Explorer++, which is why I want to try out others.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Windows Explorer also provides the whole shell for Windows. So when you click that Folder icon, you're most likely already using Explorer. It just starts another process (or window).

You might want to look into shell replacements.

---

## Update

Ok, let me go into a little bit more detail about my understanding of things.

### How the whole system works

Let's start with my desktop.
My desktop is drawn by the shell. The shell is provided by the initial `explorer.exe` process that runs when Windows starts. If I have a folder on my desktop:
[image]

I can double-click it to open it:
[image]

This created a new `explorer.exe` process which is now displaying the window that shows the contents of my folder. But there are many way the same window could have been opened.

So why did Windows to decide to use `explorer.exe` to display that folder?
Well, as I said, the desktop is already an `explorer.exe` process. So it will simply use [`ShellExecuteEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) to let the shell decide what to do with it. The shell will then create a new `explorer.exe` instance (because it is hard-wired to do so **to my knowledge**).

So what you can do, is not use `explorer.exe` to provide your shell (as you already seem to do). You can simply provide an alternative application in the registry under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

But nobody is stopping **that** new shell from calling `ShellExecuteEx()`, which would, again, invoke the default shell and, thus, `explorer.exe`!

### So, what now?

So if you **really** want to replace Windows Explorer, replace the **file** `explorer.exe`.  Because, in the end, every program **could** still try to execute `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` directly and then you have the same old Explorer again.

But, please keep in mind, I have never attempted to replace `explorer.exe` on a system, so I don't know if that would even be possible and/or stable to use.

### How does application XYZ do it?

There are several applications that simply *plug* into Explorer, like [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/). Maybe Explorer++ works the same way. This way you don't need to touch anything as your modification is always loaded into new `explorer.exe` processes. Going into detail about that process would take a whole new answer.

### What about the File-Open dialog?

This is a whole new set of problems. The *File Save* and *File Open* dialogs are part of the [Common Dialogs Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511274.aspx). Trying to replace those is hard to imagine. Pretty much the same can be said about those as I said about `explorer.exe`. But this would be far more scary.

Comment: I was once looking for exactly the same thing. Back then, I was unable to find a satisfactory solution (other than shell replacement). And every single shell replacement for Windows is simply a disappointment.

Comment: I already use a shell replacement: SharpEnviro. That's a whole different topic that I am also interested in, but my understanding is that most shell replacements actually just target the desktop environment: they replace the taskbar, start menu, give you new tool bars, change how the desktop looks and how it works. But they don't touch the file manager part of Explorer at all. That's how SharpE is, and that's how Emerge and also Aston Shell were when I tried each of them briefly. It looks like Cairo shell is one that has everything, including its own file manager, but I rather like SharpE...

Comment: Anyway, what are you saying about it being the problem? Are you saying that what I am looking for is not possible? I do realize that most likely I won't be able to replace Explorer *completely* -- for example, doing File > Open in any application will still bring up the standard Explorer dialog box. That's how it is when I use Explorer++. But still, Explorer++ definitely does take over from Explorer in virtually every other instance. Clicking "Computer" opens it in Explorer++, for example. That kind of "almost" solution is indeed possible, and it's good enough for me.

Comment: I updated my question with my understanding of things. Hopefully you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the update! A couple comments. 1.) I up-voted your post because that is some useful info in there. Those details you went into helped broaden my understanding. 2.) However, I really didn't like the way you edited my title because I feel like that hijacked my thread into topics I didn't want to get into. It makes my thread look like a duplicate of others. You're getting into some things that are pretty much the topic of this thread: http://superuser.com/q/241442/60860

Comment: Anyway, I changed the title back to my original. It's just that I had a very specific purpose for this thread: I wanted to learn about what software have the feature that I outlined. I do find it very useful what you're saying about replacing the explorer.exe, but I just want to know what programs exist that will accomplish what I want to do without me having to start messing with system files or registry entries. But maybe we can talk about both topics at the same time?

Comment: I didn't mean to drive your question in the wrong direction with the edit. I just thought the other title captured the essence of your question better. If it didn't, I'm sorry and thanks for rolling back :)

Comment: Beautiful answer!  Microsoft could make things simpler, but at the risk of breaking programs and the ire of old people.